# Visual studio 2008 Test tools

Tags: visual-studio-2008, testing

Is it possible to run in parallel a web test in visual studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it depends on the edition.  IIRC, you need team system.

See this link (scroll way down for the load testing section):
http://blogs.msdn.com/amit_chatterjee/archive/2009/01/29/web-and-load-testing-with-visual-studio-team-system.aspx